# Upgrade Karate from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 Causing Issues Getting Okta Token

Tags: karate

After upgrading Karate from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 I have a error:

'io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.CookieHeaderNames$SameSite io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.DefaultCookie.sameSite()

```
Feature: Get Bearer Token from Okta

Scenario: Get access token for OAuth2 client credentials
    Given url karate.properties['okta.server.url']
    * form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
    * form field scope = scope
    * header Authorization = call read('classpath:com/moo/g/karate/basic-auth.js') { username : '#(clientId)', password : '#(secret)' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    * def authToken = response.access_token
```

Debug console:
Gets 200 return then errors:

```
14:41:02.617 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 758
1 < 200
1 < Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2022 19:41:02 GMT
1 < Server: nginx
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < x-okta-request-id: YwUtTpqpDjtZ6CYqc2sA8gAABvQ
1 < x-xss-protection: 0
1 < p3p: CP="HONK"
1 < content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
1 < x-rate-limit-limit: 2000
1 < x-rate-limit-remaining: 1994
1 < x-rate-limit-reset: 1661283689
1 < cache-control: no-cache, no-store
1 < pragma: no-cache
1 < expires: 0
1 < expect-ct: report-uri="https://oktaexpectct.report-uri.com/r/t/ct/reportOnly", max-age=0
1 < x-content-type-options: nosniff
1 < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains
1 < X-Robots-Tag: noindex,nofollow
1 < Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
1 < Connection: Keep-Alive
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=26F3D925C7E7E003B5430ED9AFCEFCAA; Domain=login-preview.moo.com; Secure
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"access_token":"eyJraWQiOiJjTl95TE9VWHYtdzA3REQ5OXZIQXNkWDlocnZQWG0wUmJQQnpLNElJbzB3IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJ2ZXIiOjEsImp0aSI6IkFULjN5RG5WNnB5X0hTVWR1T2tiY01WZFNaNzNyRDJIWm1RalJKMUdQWWJHTVkiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLXByZXZpZXcubXV0dWFsb2ZvbWFoYS5jb20vb2F1dGgyL2F1c3B4M3c1aXdHZ0huTG9QMWQ2IiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpOi8vZGVmYXVsdCIsImlhdCI6MTY2MTI4MzY2MiwiZXhwIjoxNjYxMjg3MjYyLCJjaWQiOiIwb2EydHlmd3RlaWVRejBMQTFkNyIsInNjcCI6WyJkZWxldGUtZG9jdW1lbnQiLCJzcGVjaWFsLXJpc2stZG9jcyIsImFkZC1kb2N1bWVudCIsImdldC1kb2N1bWVudCIsInJwZC1kb2NzIiwiZ2V0LW1ldGFkYXRhIl0sInN1YiI6IjBvYTJ0eWZ3dGVpZVF6MExBMWQ3In0.JMMatbIe5N5wV0R2SKV8X_ifv_naRw16fbBEN0-WSvptim1xGcrtp7zNOurPJLLIGQlIJvRvpznBAinJqqSIOfAwe718BTfF4Ec98LlzYYXsn9HubJKedSAuM9KM51vjohkljYD9duZF2s4rtd3BZPkKE4WIZurtNb-1-F0a5LyjWdasBH7IIwK5oflDMb-Dxv7HIZck5FQkikWqQZwLTuKHOuKys1gUm3IDgQj6FSnJ6P-HfrOp1ahD4cb2RQJqKS4jQeY8Dv_Ne3sONiBbt8dqWnZGSCpwAOANwOaVUGzalOrk5At65I5ENQKL3PH4h3PdOOl21utME2LugUG8BA","scope":"delete-document special-risk-docs add-document get-document rpd-docs get-metadata"}

14:41:02.619 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:com/moo/g/karate/get-authorization-okta-token.feature:8
When method post
'io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.CookieHeaderNames$SameSite io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.DefaultCookie.sameSite()'
```

Not sure what next approach is, besides going back to 1.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely

Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on version 1.3 and issue has cleared.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Note that there were many RC versions released to get this kind of feedback earlier.

Comment: I have tried 1.2.1.RC2, 1.3.0.RC1, 1.3.0.RC2

Comment: @TMac follow the process and help the maintainers fix this (if there is a bug) else nothing happens